# cmake: generated header in subdir A needed transitively by target in subdir B

Tags: cmake

So I'm transitioning from make to cmake and I'm stuck at a point which is trivial in make because of in-source-dir building.

The following scenario:

Directory A/ generates some header, *A.h*. 
In order for other cpp/h, non-generated files to find the generated header, I've added the `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` as an include (<--assumption 1 here for being best approach)

However now in directory B/ (a sibling directory of A/) there is a particular source file which transitively through a *file.h*, which is also in A/, needs the generated *A.h* file.

The problem I face now is that file.h has the reference to A.h as `#include "A.h"` but at this point in the cmake execution the only include directories are:
B/

1. Now.. what is the best way to include A.h in directory B, should I hardcode something like: `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/path/to/include/for/A/A.h` that feels bad though
2. Another way is to generate the A.h file to the source dir, however I often see advise to not generate anything to the source directory.

Comment: Generate `A.h` to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/some-tag` and add this directory to C++ includes using command: `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/some-tag` (or better `target_include_directories`). Now you can use `#include "A.h"`

Comment: Ok, but that's roughly what I have now, this allows the files in A/ to find A.h, but when building the targets in B/ they then can't find A.h, because CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR is then in terms of B/.

Comment: Use [PROJECT_BINARY_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/PROJECT_BINARY_DIR.html) instead

Comment: Just wanted to say that @ruslo's comments can be regarded as accepted answer, ruslo can as far as I am concerned copy this to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PROJECT_BINARY_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/PROJECT_BINARY_DIR.html) variable to set up location of generated file from different directories. Note that [PROJECT_BINARY_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/PROJECT_BINARY_DIR.html) change every time you use [project](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html) command. In this case you can use `<PROJECT>_BINARY_DIR` variable:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
project(Foo)
add_subdirectory(Boo)

# Boo/CMakeLists.txt
project(Boo)
message("Boo_BINARY_DIR: ${Boo_BINARY_DIR}") # == PROJECT_BINARY_DIR
message("Foo_BINARY_DIR: ${Foo_BINARY_DIR}") # != PROJECT_BINARY_DIR
```